# Spring data @Transient in abstract class

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a strategy pattern implemented with an abstract class called presentation

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")

@JsonSubTypes({
@Type( value=PiePresentation.class, name="PIE"),
@Type( value=BarPresentation.class, name="BAR")})

public abstract class Presentation {

    String id;
    List<? extends DetailResponse> data =  new ArrayList();
    String[] variables;
    Map<String, Object> configurations;        

    @Transient
    protected ExecutionState state;
}
```

And two sub classes, here's one of them

```
public class PiePresentation extends Presentation{

    @Transient
    private List<Segment> response;

}
```

This classes are fields of another class that is stored into a mongo collection.
The problem is that spring data is storing the *state* field of the Presentation class, is like in inheritance the @Transient annotation is being ignored.

Comment: The annotations are not inherited.

Comment: Some workaround? Or any way that I don't have to duplicate a lot of code? (there's much more that the one that I posted here associated with that var)

Comment: Do you mean `PiePresentation`  and `BarPresentation` are present as value types in some entity?

Comment: That's right Eugen.

Comment: And the `response` doesn't get saved, but `state` does?

Comment: Yes, but check the desoss answer, it was an import issue. Tanks Eugen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good to me.

Are you sure that you are using the correct @Transient annotation?
It must be imported from the package *org.springframework.data.annotation*.
Don't use the javax persistence one.

Moreover be sure to use **MappingMongoConverter**. Annotation based mapping only works if you're using the MappingMongoConverter as backing converter for MongoTemplate. If you're not configuring the converter a SimpleMongoConverter will be used by default that simply serializes objects into Mongo without taking a look at any meta information whatsoever.

Comment: It was that, It was imported ok in the PiePresentation (org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;) but in the abstract class it was imported from import javax.persistence.Transient;
That's why it was ignoring it, thanks a lot desoss, I owe you a beer :)